# Unity how to get the players microsoft username

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im making a game in unity and i want the players usernames to be their microsoft username like in minecraft bedrock addition, but i dont know how to do this.

[Minecraft bedrock menu screen with username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWuhy.png)

Comment: Are you referring to Microsoft Store/Xbox Games for PC account or the account used by the user to _log into Windows?_

Answer (score 0):

This should work in C#:

```
string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

Or this:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: I believe OP is referring to Microsoft Store/Xbox Games for PC account and not the Windows user account.

Comment: In that case I think his app should require login or something to fetch correct account when the app is starting. I think that MC Bedrock is already bound to your Microsoft Account when you download it through Microsoft Store... One last thing that could easily help for non-windows devices is: SystemInfo.deviceName

Comment: Yes agreed good sir.